# Detect if webpage request if from browser versus UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webserver

Does a webserver know whether a page request is coming from a webbrowser versus a UIWebView within an app in IOS.

For example, was any webserver able to distinguish between web pages being requested from web browsers versus the Instapaper app on iOS?

Comment: might be, but I never tried. Check http request header, such as http-user-agent..

Answer (score 3):

Useragent will make the difference. Use the below detection code

```
var isWebView = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if(isWebView) {
    alert("Page serving through UIWebView");
} else {
    alert("Page serving through Browser");
}
```

Comment: Google Chrome (and other browsers) for iOS use UIWebView and they send another User Agent. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Adding CriOS to the Regex works: 
/((iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari))|(CriOS)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

Comment: The regex in the comment above will include requests from Google Chrome and similar iOS browsers (i.e. `isWebView` will evaluate to true if you get a request from one of them). If you want to exclude them instead, you can use the following: `/((iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*(Safari|CriOS)))/i`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the user-agent for each is different.

Comment: Thanks Martin, thinking more broadly here, I am wondering is there are any cases where a website (webserver) decided to block web page requests coming through a UIWebView (an app) because it is serving the content from an app other than theirs (kind of like Instapaper).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Instapaper. You'd like to be able to block traffic that comes from an app that isn't yours? That issue is more complex then your initial question, a top of head response is you'd have to introduce some other mechanism, perhaps using certificates or authentication or cookies etc. By the way an app using UIWebView can change the user agent if it wishes, so an app could pretend to be Safari.

Comment: Actually, I am thinking of it from the app developer side. I wanted to make sure that a webserver cannot selectively block web traffic coming from an app. So a UIWebView morphing user agent is actually a good idea. Thanks